# Windows CryptUIDlgSelectCertificate function in java

Tags: java, c++, applet, japplet

How to implement this c++ windows api `CryptUIDlgSelectCertificate` function in java?

```
PCCERT_CONTEXT WINAPI CryptUIDlgSelectCertificate(
  _In_  PCCRYPTUI_SELECTCERTIFICATE_STRUCT pcsc
);
```

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/windows/desktop/aa380287(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/windows/desktop/aa380287%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Is [JNA](http://jna.java.net/) useful in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that this can be done with JNA